# Do scrapy LinkExtractors end up with unique links?

Tags: scrapy

So, I have a page with a lot of articles and page numbers. Now if I want to extract an article I use:

```
Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=['article\/.+\.html']), callback='parse_article')
```

for pages I use this Rule:
    Rule(LinkExtractor(allow='page=\d+'))

so I end up with these rules:

```
rules = [
    Rule(LinkExtractor(allow='page=\d+')),
    Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=['article\/.+\.html']), callback='parse_article')
]
```

My question is, will I get repeated pages? as in, will it extract page 3 from page 1,2,4,5,6(till page 3 is no longer visible) and add it to the extracted link list? or it only keeps unique urls at the end of it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, `LinkExtractor` should only return unique links. [There is an optional parameter, `unique`, which is `True` by default](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/link-extractors.html#scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.lxmlhtml.LxmlLinkExtractor).

But that only ensures the links extracted from each page are unique. If the same link occurs on a later page, it will be extracted again.

By default, your spider should automatically ensure it doesn't visit the same URLs again, according to the [`DUPEFILTER_CLASS`](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html#dupefilter-class) setting. The only caveat to this is if you stop and start your spider again, the record of visited URLs is reset. Look at ["Jobs: pausing and resuming crawls"](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/jobs.html) in the documentation for how to persist information when you pause and resume a spider.

Comment: May I ask for clarification on your second point.
Does this mean that if a spider is going to crawl these three pages: page1.html, page2.html, and page3.html. And each page contains three links (page1.html, page2.html, page3.html), the spider will visit each link multiple times?

Or the spider will visit each link only once?

Comment: The link extractor will extract those links again on each page, but the spider should keep track using RFPDupeFilter, which will ensure the pages are only visited once. You should see "Filtered duplicate request" in the logs when this happens