# Scrapy keep all unique pages based on a list of start urls

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I want to give Scrapy a list of start urls, and have it visit each link on each of those start pages. For every link, if it hasn't been to that page before, I want to download the page and keep it locally. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the default `parse` callback to spin off all the links. [By default Scrapy does not visit the same page twice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25118156/do-scrapy-linkextractors-end-up-with-unique-links).

```
def parse(self, response):
    links = LinkExtractor().extract_links(response)
    return (Request(url=link.url, callback=self.parse_page) for link in links)

def parse_page(self, response):
    # name = manipulate response.url to be a unique file name
    with open(name, 'wb') as f:
        f.write(response.body)
```